# Pagination displays after a click on <th> values but not on load

Tags: jquery, html, css, pagination

The first image : displays on the first load its does not contain pagination below ,its displays while clicking on the tables header values like eg: customer,date etc...

[image: before]
this is how it be after clicking ,its shows a pagination and result entries 
[image: After]
How can we solve this??

Here is my code i am using

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#example').dataTable();
  } );
```

JS:

```
     //code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js
     //cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js
```

CSS:

```
    //cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/css/jquery.dataTables.css
```

Html:

```
  <head>      
       <link href="../css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>    
       <script src="../js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>      
       <script src="../js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
       <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" class="init"> 
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#example').dataTable();
            });
       </script>
      <?php
          $colspan = 2;
        ?>

            if($user_level == 1){                 
                    $queryadd = "";
                    $colspan = 1;
               }
        <?php           
        $myquery = "SELECT t_id,t_date,c_id, t_priority,t_staff, cust_fname,cust_lname,user_name from t left join t_customer on t.t_cust_id = t_customer.cust_id left join t_users on t_staff = user_id WHERE (t_status = 0) order by t_id desc;";
        $cust_attr_list = $UtilObj->FetchToArray("select attr_name, attr_db_name from t_meta");
        $ts = $TM_DBUtilObj->get_results($myquery);
        $num = $UtilObj->num_rows;

        echo "<h4><i class='icon-tags'></i> Open Tickets [ $num ]</h4>";
        if ($num > 0){
        ?>
        <table id="example" class="<?php echo $table_style_1;?>">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="<?php echo $colspan;?>" style='text-align: center;'>Action</th>                    
                <?php if($user_level <> 1){?>
                    <th>Customer</th>
                    <?php } ?>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Mails</th>
                    <th>Priority</th>
                    <th>Assigned Staff</th>
                  ?>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <?php
                foreach ( $tickets as $call )
                {
                    $t_id        = $call->t_id;
                    $c_id          = $call->c_id;                   
                    $t_date      = date("d-m-Y",$call->t_date);

                    $cust_first_name  = $call->cust_fname;
                    $cust_last_name   = $call->cust_lname;                        
                    $priority         = $call->t_priority;
                    $a_staff          = $call->t_staff;
                    $staff_name       = $call->user_name;

                    echo "<tr>\n<td style='text-align: center;'><a href='t_details.php?t_id=$t_id'><i class='icon-eye-open'></i></a></td>\n";

                    echo "<td style='text-align: center;'><a href='t_edit.php?t_id=$_id'><i class='icon-edit' title='edit'></i></a><td id=\"tooltipitem\"><A HREF=\"#\" id=\"".$cust_id."\">$cust_first_name</A></td>\n</td>\n"; 
                     echo "<td>$t_date</td>\n<td>$mail_count";

                     echo '&nbsp;&nbsp;<A HREF="t_details.php?ticket_id='.$t_id.'"><IMG SRC="../img/new-mail.png" WIDTH="19" HEIGHT="19" BORDER="0"></A>';
                     echo "</td>\n<td>$priority</td>\n";

                     echo "</td>\n<td>[$a_staff] $staff_name </td>\n";          

            }
            ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

> Pointed place : if i give '$colspan = 1' at First column "ACTION".if it's not splited into colspan = 2 then its working fine , how to fix this?

Comment: Make sure you've loaded all files of the dataTables plugin, it works just fine if you follow the instructions. Do you have any errors in your console? It would help if you paste some HTML code.

Comment: Added my html @odedta

Comment: No errors in console?

Comment: TIP: Use `PHP_EOL` instead of `\n` in order to have a line break since `PHP_EOL` is cross-platform

Comment: Check the DOM before the pagination appears, is it in the DOM?

Comment: @ odedta check latest add summary below

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83316/discussion-between-sheriff-and-odedta).

Comment: Make sure the number of `<th>` are equal to the number of `<td>`, your `foreach` loop is a bad idea since sometimes you might have less items and sometimes more items so for example you can get 10 `<td>` in one row where there should have been 5.